# github pages using gatsby does not load the index.html at root

Tags: reactjs, github, jsx, gatsby, github-pages

My Github pages is set up that from a dev branch to run a script that builds gatsby website and publishes it to the master branch where Github the serves it at `zana-a.github.io` or rather it is ought to; but it doesn't. Although `zana-a.github.io/index` `zana-a.github.io/index.html` works. I have checked the html page and other repositories and it is just odd because their websites seem to work fine.

Anyone know the solution to this or why this may be. I know i could save so much more time if I just used Netlify but I would like to use Github pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Github takes some time to ... do something. Whatever this something is, it now allows me to use the root without issue.